# A p-power inequality for Euclidean norm

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, vector-analysis, geometric-inequalities

On page 3 of the paper
"Ismail Kombe and Murad Ozaydin, Improved Hardy and Rellich Inequalities On Riemannian Manifolds, Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, Volume 361, Number 12, December 2009, Pages 6191–6203."
There are the inequalities: 
$$ |a+b|^p-|a|^p\geq c(p)|b|^p+p|a|^{p-2}a\cdot b, \qquad (1)$$
where $a,b \in \mathbb{R^{n}}$, $c(p)>0$ a constant, and $p>2$.
If $p<2$, then we have
$$ |a+b|^p-|a|^p\geq c(p)\dfrac{|b|^2}{\left(|a|+|b|\right)^{2-p}}+p|a|^{p-2}a \cdot b \qquad (2)$$.

I am looking for an upper bound for
$ |a+b|^p-|a|^p$, $p>1$ better than the trivial bound $(2^{p-1}-1)|a|^p+2^{p-1}|b|^p$ that follows from the triangle inequality.

A typical argument is exploiting Gateaux-differentiability of the Euclidean norm and the fundamental theorem of calculus to write:

$$ |a+b|^p-|a|^p=p\int_{0}^{1}|a+tb|^{p-2}(a+bt)\cdot b \;dt  $$.

Then I need to bound the integrand on the RHS from above. I don't know how to continue. In fact any reference for the proof of (1) or (2) is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "best" upper bound? Are you looking for specific terms to appear in the upper bound?

Comment: @Umberto P. I edited the question. I mean an upper bound better than the easy consequence of the triangle inequality.

Comment: When $a=b$ you have $$|a+b|^p - |a|^p = 2^p |a|^p - |a|^p = (2^p-1)|a|^p$$ and your "trivial" bound simplifies to $$ (2^{p-1} - 1)|a|^p + 2^{p-1}|a|^p = (2^p - 1)|a|^p.$$

No, you can't improve on that.

Comment: @ Umberto P. That does not mean this is the best upper bound for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let me refer you to the paper "Mitani et al., On sharp triangle inequalities in Banach spaces, J. Math. Anal. Appl. 336 (2007) 1178–1186" and the references therein. The point is there can be an upper bound that is better than the "trivial" one when $a\neq b$ and coincide with it when $a= b$.

Comment: Then perhaps you should ask a more precise question.

Comment: I found a reference for the proofs of (1) and (2): "PETER LINDQVIST, On the equation $\div(|\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u) A-\lambda |u|^{p-2}u=0$, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Volume 109. Number I. May 1990.